# Trouble with PHP loading and parsing XML

Tags: php, html, xml

Hi I have this XML File Like So:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<songs>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:40:26">
        <title>I left my heart on Europa</title>
        <artist>Ship of Nomads</artist>
    </song>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:27:42">
        <title>Oh Ganymede</title>
        <artist>Beefachanga</artist>
    </song>
    <song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:23:50">
        <title>Kallichore</title>
        <artist>Jewitt K. Sheppard</artist>
    </song>
</songs>
```

and then my HTML Document:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>

<?php
    $mysongs = simplexml_load_file('songs.xml');
    echo $mysongs->song[0]->artist;?>


</body>
</html>
```

However when I come to run the Page I get this:
[image]

Generally what am I doing wrong here ? seeing as how PHP is not displaying the artist do I need to include a library etc ? the xml file and html file are within the same folder.

Comment: `and then my HTML Document:` as in .html? There's your problem :)

Comment: Do a `view source`. You'll probably see ALL of the php code there.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file to `index.php`. Assuming you have installed PHP properly, the web server decides by the file extension of the document if the document should being processed by PHP. By default this are `*.php` documents but not `*.html` documents.

Comment: Hi I don't have php installed or on a web server generally I was doing it through my browser

Comment: You need to have a web-server installed, like the WAMP stack (Windows) if you want to run PHP, you can't run it through the `file://` protocol.

Comment: @CatLikeOlive0 This will not work. You need to install a web server and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are running this on a server that is not executing PHP.  Either that, or your file doesn't have a PHP extension, so your server doesn't know to execute the PHP.  That's why you are getting raw text.